# Regular Expression Alternatives (All Matches)

Tags: javascript, regex

thanks for looking at my question.

I have a long list of alternatives that I am trying to match in a regex:

`var re = new RegExp('o1|o2|o3|o4|o5|...','g')`

The problem that I run into is what happens if o1 is a substring of o2.  For example

`var re = new RegExp('a|b|c|ab|abc','g')`

`var s = 'abc'`

`s.match(re)` -> ["a", "b", "c"]

I would like for it to also be able to match the "ab" and "abc".  I realize if I change the ordering of the RegExp, I can get it to match the longer string, but I really want to get all matches.

What is the best way to do this?  This doesn't necessarily seem like the best (or a good way) of dealing with a long list of alternatives.  I thought of testing each alternative with its own regexp, but that seemed less efficient.

Any guidance would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want all possible matches of these alternatives? I don't think that's possible with only an expression.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.  I had used this solution in the past where I had a list of options with no overlap and it seemed to be faster than checking each option in its own regexp or using indexOf.  I think because of the potential overlap in alternatives I just need to iterate over the list :-/

Comment: Google led me to this page when I was searching for alternatives to regex. Would like to share this very useful link that I eventually found: https://github.com/VerbalExpressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only the long list of alternatives in your RegExp the better way to do it is using the `indexOf` method of `String`. Here is the code which outputs indexes of all alternatives in the string:

```
var alternatives = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'abc'],
    s = 'abc, cba',
    i,
    index;

for (i = 0; i < alternatives.length; i++) {
    index = -1;
    do {
        index = s.indexOf(alternatives[i], index+1);
        if (index !== -1) {
            console.log(alternatives[i], index);
        }
    } while (index !== -1);
}
```

Comment: so just run `indexOf` on each alternative and keep track of the matches?

Comment: indexOf doesnt work on <IE9 to add compatibility to browsers you can look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @voigtan It's `indexOf` of `String`, not of `Array`. Do not mislead people.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to match the whole string like `"abc"` then the Rgex would be:

```
^(a|b|c|ab|abc)$
```

But there is maybe an easier way, but to help you, I have to know all "alternatives" you like to check for. Maybe a shorter regex expression is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup multiple `(capturing groups)` to get all matches...  You still need to order your alternatives accordingly

Using your example:

```
var re = /((a)(b))(c)|(a)(b)|a|b|c/
var s5 = 'abc';
var s4 = 'ab';
var s3 = 'a';
var s2 = 'b';
var s1 = 'c';

console.log(s5.match(re)); // ['abc', 'ab', 'a', 'b', 'c', undef, undef]
console.log(s4.match(re)); // ['ab', undef, undef, undef, undef, 'a', 'b']
console.log(s3.match(re)); // ['a', ... undef x 6 ...]
console.log(s2.match(re)); // ['b', ... undef x 6 ...]
console.log(s1.match(re)); // ['c', ... undef x 6 ...]
```

[More info on capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references)